# When using Play Asset Delivery, how can I access the data in install-time model from html?

Tags: android, google-apps-script

Regard google play asset delivery install-time asset packs. it seems can’t directly access assets inside of these asset packs, so if I want to access the image files inside install-time from app's index.html how can I achieve it? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java#install-time-delivery

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
...
Context context = createPackageContext("com.example.app", 0);
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("asset-name");
```